# How can I stack my toolboxes stably?

Tags: tools, storage

I have two toolboxes that look like the picture below, with handles which lie down but still make a "bump" about a 1/2" high in the middle of the top so I can't make a stable stack when not in use.  I'm considering doing something to make up the height, a ridge along the ends of the bottom of the top one.  I was thinking maybe I'd epoxy a short length of 1/2" tubing.  Any thoughts?

[image: tool boxes]

Comment: If you add 1/2" high *feet* to each box, you will not only be able to stack them, but they will be raised above any damp floor or ground and thus minimize rusting.

Comment: What meaning of *secure* do you mean?  Safe from burglars, safe from falling over, safe from kids, etc.?

Comment: Safe from falling over.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comment of adding feet to the bottoms by pop riveting rubber bumpers or cushions

[image]

and doing the same with 4 furniture cups. They are soft or hard plastic that you can fasten to the top top keep the newly aplied feet in place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: n the lower chest, remove top handle and add side handles. You might also want to design something so the two interlock, to prevent the top case sliding off too easily.